# how to assign not null condition in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements

i am working on windows8 vb.net mobile application in that application i am checking not null conditions.here below i have attaching the code file.

```
If JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText() IsNot Nothing _
And JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).ReasonCodeDesc() IsNot Nothing Then
    mEventNotes = "Event text: " + JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText() + _ 
                  "\nReason: " + JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).ReasonCodeDesc()
ElseIf JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText().Trim() IsNot Nothing Then
    mEventNotes = "Event text: " + JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText()
Else
    mEventNotes = JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText().Trim() + _
                  "\n" + JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).ReasonCodeDesc().Trim()
End If
```

Please give me any suggestion how to write not null conditions in vb.net?

Comment: `JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText() IsNot Nothing` like this - you already have it written.

Comment: `JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText().Trim() IsNot Nothing` this might be better using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` since it can be not nothing and still 0 length, which kind of seems what you are after

Comment: Depending on what `JobEventAllDetailsSortnew` is you probably also want to check that it `Contains(value)` before you act upon it.

Comment: @Plutonix: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` then.

Comment: All this nothing; I feel like such a nihilist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it a few ways, you could do:

```
Value <> Nothing
```

Or

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(JobEventAllDetailsSortnew.Item(value).EventText())

End If
```

To name a couple of ways.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should use `Value IsNot Nothing` to check for not being Nothing.